# Finding a friend on Overwatch by in game name

Tags: overwatch, battle.net

As per a suggestion from the OW university/comp subreddits I have been recording my matches to look for ways to improve myself.

During one of these reviews I noticed one match where I sent a friend request to the wrong person. The dude was super positive, doing great and communicating. When I looked up someone else had their mic open, thought it was my new friend ,and I sent it to them instead. I was actually sad that I didn't get a response but went on with life.

So now I need to find this guy, he's long gone from my recent groups and typing his name in isn't giving me any results because I need the battle tag. Looks like you can only add by recent players, battle tag or directly from battle.net

Am I missing something simple/dumb here?

Dupe edit: This match was weeks ago and the player is not in that list. I have no way to contact them. All I have is their in game name that I can see from the replay I recorded. The linked duplicate does not address this scenario.

Comment: Looking for how to do it without battle tag / recent players. It is not answered by that post.

Comment: It seems to me that if you don't know the name of the player you want to connect with, and that player doesn't show up in any list you have access to, then you can't connect with them.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a fuzzy search or something that I didn't know  about in bnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Social), it seems that the only way of adding people to your friends list (apart from the Recent Players) section is by adding them via their Battle Tag, which you do not have. Apart from these methods, there seems to be no other way of adding players to your friends list.

> It seems to me that if you don't know the name of the player you want to connect with, and that player doesn't show up in any list you have access to, then you can't connect with them.
>   – Mage Xy